# Problems setting with two pam-password-modules in centos at the same time

Tags: linux, centos, pam

I would like to prevent the use of last passwords and keeping password complexity.

But if I use pam_pwquality.so and pam_pwhistory.so at the same time, it doesn't work properly.

For example, I set a minimum length of 8 and disable the last two passwords in the system-auth file.

```
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=8
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so remember=2 retry=3
```

If I enter the last password that meets the complexity, pwhistory blocks me, but after that, it is possible to change the password without complexity. -> Does the first module become invalid if the check passes to the second module?

The situation is similar when pwquality and pwhistory are reversed.

```
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so remember=2 retry=3
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=8
```

It works as follows.

```
$passwd

Enter the last password -> failed by pwhistory module

Enter short password -> failed by pwquality module

Enter the last password -> success regardless of pwhistory module
```

Can't I check the complexity and the last password condition at the same time?

Comment: hmm, maybe set `retry=1` so that the password change attempt stops when anything fails? it looks like PAM is getting confused with the multiple attempts, I guess

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `use_authtok` parameter when stacking `pwhistory` with other password changing modules (like `pwquality`, which changes the original chosen password):

```
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=8
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so remember=2 retry=3 use_authtok
```

You can look at the man-page for the `pwhistory` module using

```bash
man pam_pwhistory
```

Excerpt from the man-page:

> use_authtok
>
> When password changing enforce the module to use the new
> password provided by a previously stacked password module
> (this is used in the example of the stacking of the
> pam_cracklib module documented below).